# Android Sqlite: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: aggregate functions are not allowed in the GROUP BY clause

Tags: android, sqlite, group-by

Having a weird issue here where a query executes just fine in Sqlite DB Browser on my desktop - results exactly as expected - but throws an exception when executing a Cursor in Android (4.4.2). I'm new to both Android and Sqlite so maybe there's a "gotcha" I haven't discovered yet.

Simple query:

```
select 
max(_id) as '_id', 
max(envid) as 'envid', 
max(action) as 'action', 
max(title) as 'title', 
max(cast(version as INTEGER)) as 'version', 
max(layout) as 'layout' 
from template  
where direction = 'return'  
group by title
```

Exception:

> E/AndroidRuntime(20731): Caused by:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: aggregate functions are not
>   allowed in the GROUP BY clause (code 1): , while compiling: select
>   max(_id) as '_id', max(envid) as 'envid', max(action) as 'action',
>   max(title) as 'title', max(cast(version as INTEGER)) as 'version',
>   max(layout) as 'layout' from template where direction = 'return' group
>   by title

I'd expect to see that if I put an aggregate function in the group by clause...but I haven't.

Comment: I suppose `max()` is an aggregate function.

Comment: Yeah, after typing this up I wondered if the error meant the aggregate being used in the select. I whittled it down to this and it works fine: "select _id, envid, action, title, max(cast(version as INTEGER)) as 'version', layout from template where direction = 'return' group by title" Funny how this wasn't an issue outside of Android, with a direct query? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it - which is all I really needed (see comment from Rohit5k2 above.)

```
select _id, envid, action, title, max(cast(version as INTEGER)) as 'version', layout from template where direction = 'return' group by title
```